Can't get access to referenced objects / Array using GROQ query for Sanity.IO
Here is my schema setup:
How do I query Groq to return the navItems and the navItemUrls within one query to use in a map function?
The only thing I can return is the top-level properties of personalnav when performing the GROQ query.  I need to be able to use all of these properties to populate the dynamic data to each navigation button and map over them dynamic to leverage a server component in nextjs.
const personalnav = {
  name: "personalnav",
  type: "document",
  title: "Personal Navigation",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "title",
      type: "string",
      title: "Title"
    },
    {
      name: "id",
      type: "string",
      title: "Id"
    },
    {
      name: "navItems",
      type: "array",
      title: "Navigation items",
      of: [{ type: "navItem" }]
    }
  ]
};

const navItem = {
name: "navItem",
type: "object",
title: "NavItem",
fields: [
  {
    name: "text",
    type: "string",
    title: "Name of Link"
  },
  {
    name: "description",
    type: "string",
    title: "Link Description that follows the Name of Link"
  },
  {
    name: "navItemUrl",
    type: "link", // references link object
    title: "Nav Item URL"
  }
]
};

export default navItem;


const link = {
name: "link",
type: "object",
title: "Link",
fields: [
  {
    name: "externalContent",
    title: "Content is from an external source",
    type: "boolean"
  },
  {
    name: "linkUrl",
    title: "Link URL",
    description:
      "Use this field to add a link to the source. For external links use full url e.g. ‘https://google.com/’. For internal links use the page path e.g. ‘companies’",
    type: "string"
  }
]
};

export default link;
const navItem = {
name: "navItem",
type: "object",
title: "NavItem",
fields: [
  {
    name: "text",
    type: "string",
    title: "Name of Link"
  },
  {
    name: "description",
    type: "string",
    title: "Link Description that follows the Name of Link"
  },
  {
    name: "navItemUrl",
    type: "link", // references link object
    title: "Nav Item URL"
  }
]
};

export default navItem;


